# Hiding/showing views vs creating/deleting views during runtime

Tags: android

As seen in the picture below, the people below have different statuses, depending on if they're already friends or not.

How would one go about and to achieve this?

1. Have two differnt `Views` **hidden** (gone) by default and only have one of them **visible** when needed
2. **Create** one of the `View`s during runtime as it's needed, and add it to an empty container
3. Other

[image: ListView of friends with different statuses]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should consider rewording your question to something along the lines of "what are some methods to achieve X" rather than "What is the best way to do X" as the latter is primarily an opinion based question which tends to attract down voters like flies to rotten meat...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I changed the question and I hope it's not as rotten anymore and won't attract those nasty flies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding two different views will increase the number of nodes in the view hierarchy. Drawing view hierarchies on screen are expensive as they are traversed twice during drawing the layout.

In your example, any one of the action is displayed at once - either "Chat", or "Add Friend". So, it's better to keep a single view, with dynamic icons and actions.

You can add a single button, and dynamically change it's behaviour like this (pseudo code):

```
Button actionBtn;

if(USER_IS_A_FRIEND){

   actionBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_chat);
   actionBtn.setOnClickListener(LISTENER_FOR_OPENING_CHAT_WINDOW);

} else {

   actionBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_add_friend);
   actionBtn.setOnClickListener(LISTENER_FOR_ADDING_AS_FRIEND);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what if the two Views were different kind of Views? E.g. one is a button, but the other one is a TextView.

Comment: In that case you should add different views. Dynamically adding them will again reduce the layout cost, but will increase the processing time. Based on how complex is the rest of your layout, you can choose between dynamic / static layout there.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you for your input.